# Android build fail only on Windows

Tags: android, windows, gradle

I'm experiencing a build error on a project that consists of about 6 bundles (android library projects) and each one of them contain about 10 modules only when I try to build it in a Windows machine (working fine in Mac).

At some point this started happening (didn't happen before) and I have no way of knowing precisely when (I rarely use windows and many people commit on these bundles/modules)

I get about 170 errors and the first ones are:

```
:bundle-module:processDebugResources

C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\values\values.xml:807:5-965:13: AAPT: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-hdpi-v4\values-hdpi-v4.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\values-hdpi-v4\values-hdpi-v4.xml:3:5-7:14: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'barLength'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\values-hdpi-v4\values-hdpi-v4.xml:3:5-7:14: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'drawableSize'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\values-hdpi-v4\values-hdpi-v4.xml:3:5-7:14: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'gapBetweenBars'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml:20: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\24.2.1\res\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml:12:5-15:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabGravity'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\24.2.1\res\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml:12:5-15:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabMode'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-land\values-land.xml:7: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\24.2.1\res\values-land\values-land.xml:3:5-6:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabGravity'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\24.2.1\res\values-land\values-land.xml:3:5-6:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabMode'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-large-v4\values-large-v4.xml:10: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-large-v4\values-large-v4.xml:11: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize'.
C:\project\trunk\project-bundle\bundle-module\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'
......
......
```

Things I tried:

- Clean project.
- Invalidate cache and restart.
- Re-checkout entire project.
- Move project close to the root of the drive (for file names lenght issues).
- Try on different Windows machines.
- Delete Android Studio, properties and SDK and install from scratch.
- Switching the support libraries versions.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your build.gradle file

Comment: Hey, the problem was in the project level build.gradle file... Sorry I didn't post a screenshot but I couldn't do it for security reasons.. In the answer I posted code removing the sensitive info.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a colleague of mine saw the question, and found the solution so I post it here. He pointed out that in our build.gradle we had the following task:

```
String updateStylesResourcesFromConfig(String resourcesTag) {
File jsonFile = file("bundle-module/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.company.product/config-bundle/${version}/assets/config/app/styles/android/styles.json")
println "bundle-module/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.company.product/config-bundle/${version}/assets/config/app/styles/android/styles.json"

if (jsonFile.exists() && !jsonFile.text.isEmpty()) {
    println "Updating style file in ${resourcesTag} mode"
    // Reading json file text
    def jsonContent = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)

    if (!jsonContent.isEmpty()) {
        //Applying JSON file content
        def primaryColor = jsonContent.Variables.primaryColor
        def secondaryColor = jsonContent.Variables.secondaryColor
        def primaryTextColor = jsonContent.Variables.primaryTextColor

        println "bundle-module/build/intermediates/res/merged/${resourcesTag.toLowerCase()}/values/values.xml"
        File valuesXMLFile = file("bundle-module/build/intermediates/res/merged/${resourcesTag.toLowerCase()}/values/values.xml")

        if (valuesXMLFile.exists()) {
            def response = new XmlParser().parseText(valuesXMLFile.text)
            response.color.each {
                def value
                switch (it.@name) {
                    case "primaryColor":
                        value = primaryColor
                        break
                    case "secondaryColor":
                        value = secondaryColor
                        break
                    case "primaryTextColor":
                        value = primaryTextColor
                        break
                }
                if (value != null) {
                    replaceColorValue(it, value)
                }
            }
            valuesXMLFile.text = XmlUtil.serialize(response)
        }
    }
}
}
```

For some reason, on Windows, this doesn't work as expected.